# How to solve route not define in laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

When I update data, I want the url like this :

http://mysystem.dev/users/proses?kdbulan=01&thang=2017

My code to update data is like this :

```
public function update($id, UpdateUserRequest $request)
{
    ....
    return redirect(route('users.proses?kdbulan=01&thang=2017'));
}
```

When executed, there exist error like this :

> Route [users.proses?kdbulan=01&thang=2017] not defined.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What does your route corresponding to this redirect look like in your route file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters should be passed as an array in the secondary parameter.

```
route('users.proses', ['kdbulan' => 01, 'thang' => 2017]);
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers

Answer (score 0):

you can use

route('users.proses', ['kdbulan' => 01, 'thang' => 2017]);